# Sustain the changes in NPM dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

i am working on a REACT web application. I am using react-datasheet library and installed in using NPM. Now to make it support IE11, i have done some changes in the javascript file installed by NPM. This works in my local machine but what is the best way to sustain the changes during deployment.

One way is to add all the JS files in the SRC folder but is that the best approach. All i did is added one handler to support paste operation in IE11. Is there a way to handle the scenario without changing the code in the npm_module folder?

Comment: The best way is to never make changes to anything inside `node_modules` directory. You'd make your code work well by making changes to your own scripts, push an issue to the dependency's contributors and ask them to make a fix, or create your own pull request to the dependency's repo.

Comment: Do i need to paste complete folder in src? In that case, what should i change from import ReactDataSheet from 'react-datasheet' to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to remove the edited particular package out of the node_modules folder and make it part of your *src* folder. In addition to that you will also have to change the import locations to point to the folder in the *src* folder.

Comment: Do i need to paste complete folder in src? In that case, what should i change from import ReactDataSheet from 'react-datasheet' to?

Comment: Yes you have to paste the entire ReactDataSheet folder into your src. To import you will have to use relative paths similar to how you import components from other folders. The ReactDataSheet might contain some dependencies you might have to install them too if it is missing

Comment: ok that works, is it the best approach? I want to add a event handler in the javascript file, is it possible to inject or override the js files without changing in the node_module ?

Comment: You can try to import the node_modules into a higher order component and do some changes there .If you're not sure as to what you're doing it might be cumbersome . If you plan to use the modified package often and It has the relevant open source permissions, you can try making it into your own npm package and use it.